# Jenkins Pipeline script from SCM shares Perforce workspace with Sync inside of script (different stream/depot)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, perforce

I am looking for help with with our Jenkins Pipeline setup. I had a Jenkins pipeline job working just fine, where the groovy script was checked out from a Perforce stream (in stage "Declarative: Checkout SCM") and then run. The script itself performs, at its core, a `p4 sync` and a `p4 reconcile`.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            customWorkspace "workspaces/MY_WORKSPACE"
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Sync') {
            steps {
                script {
                    p4sync(
                        charset: 'none',
                        credential: '1',
                        format: "jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-MY_WORKSPACE",
                        populate: syncOnly(force: false, have: true, modtime: false, parallel: [enable: false, minbytes: '1024', minfiles: '1', threads: '4'], pin: '', quiet: true, revert: true),
                        source: streamSource('//depot/STREAM')
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Reconcile') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '1', passwordVariable: 'SVC_USER_PW', usernameVariable: 'SVC_USER_NAME')]) {
                        bat label: 'P4 reconcile', true, script:
                            """
                                p4 -c "%P4_CLIENT%" -p "%P4_PORT%" -u ${SVC_USER_NAME} -P ${SVC_USER_PW} -s reconcile -e -a -d -f "//depot/STREAM/some/folder/location/*.file"
                            """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Old Jenkins Pipeline Configuration]

Due to an exterior requirement, we decided to move all our pipeline script files to a separate depot on the same Perforce server and changed the pipeline script checkout accordingly.
[image: New Jenkins Pipeline Configuration]

Now, the pipeline script checkout step ("Declarative: Checkout SCM") will create a new workspace called `jenkins-NODE_NAME-buildsystems` (for the pipeline script depot `//buildsystems`) which will use the same local workspace root directory `D:\some\path\workspaces\MY_WORKSPACE` on the build node as the actual workspace `jenkins-NODE_NAME-MY_WORKSPACE`, created and synced in the first pipeline step by `p4sync`. This means that Perforce creates two workspaces with the same local workspace root directory (which can cause all sorts of problems in itself). In addition, in the pipeline script, the P4 environment variable `P4_CLIENT` points to the wrong workspace `jenkins-NODE_NAME-buildsystems` (so the reconcile won't work), which should only have been used by the pipeline script checkout, not by the pipeline itself.

Which brings me to my question. How can I separate the workspaces of the pipeline script checkout and of the `p4sync` in the pipeline script? In the pipeline I can specify a `customWorkspace`, but not in the Jenkins configuration for the pipeline script checkout, and the latter weirdly seems to follow that `customWorkspace` statement, maybe because `jenkins-NODE_NAME-MY_WORKSPACE` had already been opened by Perforce on the node...?

Any hints are much appreciated.

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: As a workaround, we host all our pipeline scripts now separately from the Perforce depot in a git repository.

Comment: I am encountering this issue and would like to know if there is a solution that does not involve using a separate scm.

Comment: You can do a Lightweight checkout which just reads the Jenkinsfile without actually creating a separate workspace which solves some issues. However, if you reference external groovy scripts, lightweight checkout does not work unless you p4sync those external scripts down in your Jenkinsfile before loading them.

Comment: @ChadVernon We were doing Lightweight checkouts (see screenshots), but that did not help. One way to seemingly avoid the issue is by not using p4sync, and instead do direct calls to the p4 command-line application. However, I am not actively working on the above-mentioned setup anymore. We switched build systems.